# I have a slight problem with post table in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a simple university project for an online course site like Udemy.

This form for adding a course contains the course data and a dynamic table with a button that adds a new row.
My problem is POST data, I don't know how to get the table data to store in the Database.

**edit:**
I know how to use action"test.php".
I have created sign-up and login pages.
i know I can get post data example $email = $_POST['email'];
my problem is how I get a table

php code(I know all of it html):

```
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <div>
                    <label for="titleC">title course</label>
                    <input type="text" name="titleC" id="titleC" required>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="Age">Choose a Rating Age:</label>

                    <select name="Age" id="Age" required>
                        <option value="12">12+</option>
                        <option value="16">16+</option>
                        <option value="18">18+</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="Cprice">Course Price</label>
                    <input type="number" name="Cprice" id="Cprice" min="0" required>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="Categories">Choose a Categories:</label>
                    <select name="Categories" id="Categories">
                        <option value="Development">Development</option>
                        <option value="IT">IT</option>
                        <option value="Design">Design</option>
                        <option value="Photography & Video">Photography & Video</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="img">Select image:</label>
                    <input type="file" id="img" name="img" accept="image/*">
                </div>
                <table id="listVideo">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Link</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" id="txtName" name="name[]" /></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="txtLink" name="link[]" /></td>
                            <td><input type="button" onclick="Add()" value="Add" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
                <div class="soloButton">
                    <button type="submit" name="addcourse-submit" value="submit">submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

js code:

```
function Add() {
    var txtName = document.getElementById("txtName");
    var txtCountry = document.getElementById("txtLink");
    AddRow(txtName.value, txtCountry.value);
    txtName.value = "";
    txtCountry.value = "";
};



  function Remove(button) {
        //Determine the reference of the Row using the Button.
        var row = button.parentNode.parentNode;
        var name = row.getElementsByTagName("TD")[0].innerHTML;
        if (confirm("Do you want to delete: " + name)) {
    
            //Get the reference of the Table.
            var table = document.getElementById("listVideo");
    
            //Delete the Table row using it's Index.
            table.deleteRow(row.rowIndex);
        }
    };

function AddRow(name, txtLink) {
    //Get the reference of the Table's TBODY element.
    var tBody = document.getElementById("listVideo").getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];

    //Add Row.
    row = tBody.insertRow(-1);

    //Add Name cell.
    var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
    cell.innerHTML = name;

    //Add txtLink cell.
    cell = row.insertCell(-1);
    cell.innerHTML = txtLink;

    //Add Button cell.
    cell = row.insertCell(-1);
    var btnRemove = document.createElement("INPUT");
    btnRemove.type = "button";
    btnRemove.value = "Remove";
    btnRemove.setAttribute("onclick", "Remove(this);");
    cell.appendChild(btnRemove);
}
```

The dynamic table was taken from one of the tutorials.

Thank you

[English is not my native language sorry]

Comment: There's no PHP code there, just HTML.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: When you add a row, it needs to contain `<input>` elements with the values you want to send to the server.

Comment: Your current action is "" which means it posts back to this page. This can be ideal for a single page application, but there are a couple ways to handle this data. You can add php to your page to detect if the $_POST value is set and then handle it, alternatively you can watch for the post action in javascript and send the data to another endpoint / store it that way. Alternatively you can set the action to another endpoint and handle the $_POST variable there.

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-form-handling.php - you don't seem to have a specific, concise problem as much as a lack of understanding. Please know that no offense is meant. We've all been there and are all there for something we want to achieve at almost all times. Just saying you may find reading more helpful than anyone here can be.